# Asp.net Treeview on internet explorer takes long time

Tags: asp.net, performance, internet-explorer, treeview

I have a web application which is taking a lot of time on IE while same page takes 1/10th time on firefox and chrome. Any idea about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

1. Profiling the Javascript
2. Ensuring that the problem is client, not server side (Chrome/ FF may have cached it)
3. What type of tree view is it? Have you checked forums?
4. Does it have 'issues' with specific IE versions?
5. Have you tried disabling any IE add-ons you have?

Comment: The issue is for IE (client side) and for IE 6-8